# Problema com a syntax highlight para a tag "mysql"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tags, pergunta-específica, syntax-highlighting

Coloquei [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7863/223) onde reparei que a *syntax highlight* não é assumida mediante a tag em uso [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), sendo necessário deixar o comentário para forçar a mesma:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
```

Capturas de tela em baixo após a colocação da pergunta:

- Pergunta sem o comentário

  [image: Captura de Tela]
- Pergunta com o comentário

  [image: Captura de Tela]

Isto é uma ["Glitch-in-the-Matrix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7LVQ.jpg) ou efectivamente existe um problema no âmbito desta pergunta que quebra a *syntax highlight*?

Comment: O problema ocorreu no preview, ou com a pergunta já postada? Pergunto porque o preview não destaca o código com base nas tags.

Comment: @bfavaretto Após a colocação da pergunta, mas o preview enquanto escrevemos destaca o código, é preciso é tirar o _focus_ da edição da mesma ;)

Comment: Ué Zuul, testei inclusive tirando o foco, mas pra mim isso só funciona se existe `<!-- language: lang-x -->`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pois, com a tag mysql não funciona, com as outras funciona, quer dizer, eu sou mais de respostas e nas respostas se tirar o _focus_ da mesma, um dois segundos _et voilá_, _preview_ direitinho para conferir antes de "postar". Mas tenho ideia que nas perguntas também acontece (agora só testando).

Comment: @bfavaretto Entre ontem e hoje tive oportunidade de testar a syntax-highlight _preview_ ao criar/editar pergunta e resposta. Funciona em ambos, é só mesmo tirar o _focus_. Não requer o comentário, basta ter uma tag que tenha associada uma regra de syntax-highlight. Contudo, para o caso do referido na minha pergunta, nem funcionou no _preview_ nem após colocação da pergunta.

Comment: Então a conclusão é que a tag mysql não está associada à sintaxe de SQL? O Gabe tem uma ferramenta pra resolver isso.